# Is mean time, considered without the variance, reliable?

Tags: standard-deviation

My company (which does audits and legal cases) is in the process of implementing a strict time allocation schedule for the employees. That is, we will be given X minutes to complete an audit, for instance.

When my colleagues and I pointed out that the amount of time would not be enough, the manager replied that, on average, X is an adequate length of time. Some audits takes less time, some more, he said.

These audits vary considerably in length. Some, by the time they reach my desk, are fairly cut and dry, and can be processed quickly; others require the involvement of several other people, other departments in the organization, etc., and end up taking much longer.

The manager does not believe that we should be paid for the time spent analyzing the case, then the time we spend waiting for outside parties (over whom we have no control) to do their part. This approach naturally distorts the mean time the manager has calculated for each activity.

My question: what are some arguments that can be made that, in a business with such high variance in time length, the mean is not a reliable measure?

Comment: This is not really a mathematical question. I suggest you carefully track the actual times for several weeks (or months) and prepare a spreadsheet/histogram showing the historical data. Then you and your manager can figure out an appropriate time charging strategy.

Comment: The reliability of the mean is not the issue here. The issue is your (mean) boss. I agree with Ethan- this is not a mathematical question. The issue is this: your boss doesn't understand the basic project management fact that predictions are just predictions, not mathematical facts. I mean, where did he even get the figure for $X$ from in the first place? If I were him, and I wanted to incentivize productivity, I'd do so by awarding fast resolution times rather than penalizing slow ones. This has been shown to be much more effective.